# How to add button to foreignObject in d3 SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to create popup `div` inside my SVG and add buttons to that `div`.I create `foreignObject` inside SVG and add button to that foreignObject.I am trying to call a java script function using button on click event.but inside foreignObject button don't give its functionality.

```
.on('mouseover', function() {
    var trashfuntion = function(){
        console.log("click")
    }
                var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
                    .attr({
                        'x': anchor.w - tip.w,
                        'y': anchor.h + tip.h,
                        'width': foWidth,
                        'class': 'svg-tooltip'
                    });
                var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
                    .append('div')
                    .attr({
                        'class': 'tooltip'
                    });
                div.append('div')
                    .attr('class', 'lead')
                    .html('<button onclick="trashfuntion()">Click Me</button>' );
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution you found on that will help me and save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<svg id="mySvg"></svg>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("#mySvg")
var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
  .attr({
  'x': 20, //anchor.w - tip.w,
  'y': 20, //anchor.h + tip.h,
  'width': 220,//foWidth,
  'class': 'svg-tooltip'
  });
 var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
   .append('div')
   .attr({
   'class': 'tooltip'
    });
 div.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'lead')
    .html('<button onclick="trashfuntion()">Click Me</button>' );

 function trashfuntion() {
     console.log("click")
 }
</script>
```

Try a different browser.

- Edge 25.1 doesn't work. Even render the button.
- You tell me Chrome neither
- I'm using Opera 38 and works well

Obviously this a browser implementation dependent. You'll need some workaround.-

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: chrome web browser

Answer (score -1):

As per another stackoverflow thread: [D3 - Unable to get data parameter on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139002/d3-unable-to-get-data-parameter-on-click-event)

you can use

```
.on("click", function(e, d) {..})
```

where d is the node data